# What is the "system-dependent default" thread pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, nio

From the [`AsynchronousFileChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html) API:

> When an AsynchronousFileChannel is created without specifying a thread pool then the channel is associated with a **system-dependent default thread pool** that may be shared with other channels.

I haven't seen this terminology anywhere else, and I haven't found any concrete explanation via web search. What exactly is the system-dependent default thread pool? What are its characteristics? And how might they vary between systems?

Comment: Well, I'm blind `The default thread pool is configured by the system properties defined by the` [`AsynchronousChannelGroup`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousChannelGroup.html) `class.`

Comment: Just go and answer your own question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read the documentation a bit more:

> The default thread pool is configured by the system properties defined
>   by the AsynchronousChannelGroup class.

And if you jump [there](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousChannelGroup.html), you see:

> In addition to groups created explicitly, the Java virtual machine
>   maintains a system-wide default group that is constructed
>   automatically. Asynchronous channels that do not specify a group at
>   construction time are bound to the default group. The default group
>   has an associated thread pool that creates new threads as needed. The
>   default group may be configured by means of system properties defined
>   in the table below. Where the ThreadFactory for the default group is
>   not configured then the pooled threads of the default group are daemon
>   threads.

...followed by the list of configuration parameters.

Comment: I know, I saw that right after posting the question. I blame it on being up all night. But thank you.

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy It happens to everyone.